# Como pegar o nome e os atributos das tabelas de um banco de dados MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como pegar os nomes de todas as tabelas do *banco de dados* MySQL?

Como pegar os atributos (nome, tipo, etc...) de uma determinada tabela no banco de dados MySQL?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Para visualizar as tabelas de uma database:

```sql
SHOW TABLES;
```

Para visualizar a estrutura da tabela com nome, tipo, etc.:

```sql
DESC nome_da_tabela;
```

Comment: Se precisar especificar um Banco:
`SHOW TABLES FROM banco`

Comment: É possível escolher o banco utilizando o comando `USE nomeDoBanco;`, antes do `SHOW TABLES;`

Comment: **SHOW TABLES** só responde uma parte da pergunta.  Os atributos das tabelas estão no INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: Sim, você pode utilizar o information_schema para visualizar informações mais completas da tabela, mas, se você precisa apenas de informações básicas como nome, típo, etc. você pode usar o "DESC" (Conforme mencionado nessa mesma resposta) que é mais simples.

Answer (score 17):

Você pode usar a consulta:

```sql
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'nome-do-banco';
```

Ela mostra os nomes das tabelas e também informações como a engine usada, data de criação, etc.

Answer (score 7):

O correto é fazer uma consulta no banco INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
Você vai conseguir dados como o type das tabelas, avg do tamanho dos registros, além dos nomes e o Storage Engine.

```sql
DESC INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Vai te dar um bom conhecimento do que pode procurar por tabela.
Lembrando que **TODO** comando "SHOW" tem correlação com tabelas no INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Answer (score 7):

Pegando os dados das colunas de uma determinada tabela:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = '<tabela>';
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select * from all_tables where tables like '%tabela desejada%'
```

Comment: Isso é Oracle! Não MySQL!