# PHP - Popular dropdown utilizando nome de tabelas de um banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

O título já é auto-explicativo. Já tentei de tudo, mas sinto que tudo que fiz está completamente errado, haha. Se alguém puder me ajudar, preciso fazer um dropdown onde os valores a serem selecionados serão nomes das tabelas do meu banco de dados. Obrigado.

[EDIT]
O jeito mais fácil que eu vejo é puxar todas as tabelas através da função mysqli_list_tables e depois eu iria utilizar um while, ou for pra imprimir isso no dropdown. A questão é que nem essa função simples abaixo está funcionando. Eu tentei deixar apenas a parte fundamental (a função de listar tabelas) para fins de testes e mesmo assim, nada funciona. (Inclusive, no meu arquivo index, após chamar a função dropdownAnos() nada mais funciona).

```
function dropdownAnos () {
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "root";
  $banco = "teste";

  mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass);

  $tabelas = mysqli_list_tables($banco);

  print_r($tabelas);
}
```

Eu já  mudei esse código infinitas vezes, tentei de todas as maneiras possíveis e essa foi a versão mais simples que consegui chegar. Mesmo assim, não funciona. (Ainda bem que tenho salvo no github, senão já teria perdido tudo haha).

[EDIT FINAL] Consegui fazer, pessoal. Vou postar a resposta, caso alguém caia nesse tópico:

```
function dropdownAnos () {
  $str = "";
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'teste');

  $teste = $db->query('SHOW TABLES');

  while ($t = $teste->fetch_array()) {
    $str = $str .  "<option>" . $t[0] .  "</option><br>";
  }

  echo $str;
}
```

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.

Comment: @michael por favor poste o que fez!

Comment: Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo stackoverflow, conheça um pouco das regras e boas práticas. Depois, edite sua pergunta e insira o código do que você já tentou...

Comment: O título não é auto-explicativo por si só, precisamos do código pra poder te ajudar. Fica difícil saber o que você precisa se você não nos mostrar o que está tentando fazer.

Comment: Essa função não existe na extensão `MySQLi` só na antiga.

Comment: @rray então o jeito seria fazer uma consulta do tipo "show tables from $banco"? Já tentei e não funcionou

Comment: E você já tentou consultar `select * from information_schema.tables` - [Referencia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql#8334552)

Comment: @MarcoGiovanni já sim, mas devo ter feito algo errado. Consegui fazer utilizando "show tables", postei a resposta na pergunta, obrigado.

Comment: @MichaelSampietro deixei a guia aberto aqui e não tinha atualizado hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe uma função correspondente a `mysql_list_tables()` para extensão MySQLi, o jeito é fazer um consulta na mão mesmo.

Pode listar todas as tabelas da database atual, consultando o `information_schema` ou os seus atalhos (`SHOW TABLES`).

```
function listarTabelas(){
   $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'database');
   $sql = 'show tables';
   $result = $db->query($sql);
   return $result->fetch_all();
}

function criarOptions($itens){
    $options = '';
    foreach($itens as $item){
       $options .= sprintf('<option>%s</option>', $item); 
    }
    return $options;
}
```

A chamada pode ficar assim:

```
<?php $options = criarOptions(listarTabelas()); ?>
<select>
   <?php echo $options; ?>
</select>
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Como pegar o nome de todas as tabelas de uma database MySql](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/62/91)

Comment: Obrigado, consegui fazer de uma outra maneira: