# SQL para procurar em todo o banco

Tags: sql, select

Existe algum comando para fazer um select em todas as tabelas de um banco de dados em mysql? Tipo eu tenho várias tabelas no meu banco de dados com conteúdo diverso. Preciso de uma forma que um usuário possa procurar por uma palavra chave em todas as tabelas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo... Criei 3 tabelas totalmente distintas e coloquei em cada uma 1 conteúdo em comum (meu nome, Walmir). Veja os dados que inseri para exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para você efetuar a consulta nessas 3 tabelas distintas, você poderia fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT 'tb_a' as ref, a.nome as result FROM tb_a a WHERE a.nome LIKE '%Walmir%' 
UNION
SELECT 'tb_b' as ref, b.descricao as result FROM tb_b b WHERE b.descricao LIKE '%Walmir%' 
UNION
SELECT 'tb_c' as ref, c.conteudo as result FROM tb_c c WHERE c.conteudo LIKE '%Walmir%'
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja por favor se resolve o que você precisa. Qualquer coisa deixa um comentário que eu modifico esta resposta. Ok?

Comment: muito bom. Entendi o uso do UNION que não sabia usar. Preciso implementar uma busca em um site, porém buscando em várias tabelas através de uma palavra chave. Mas percebi que isso vai gerar um problema que é apresentar os dados ao usuário. Mas obrigado.

Comment: Fico feliz em pode ajudar. ;)

Answer (score 1):

A resposta simples é: não existe UM comando que faça  isso.  Você vai ter que implementar vários selects e unir eles, ou criar um script ou stored procedure para conseguir isso, usando a tabela information_schema.

É importante estar ciente que esse tipo de busca pode comprometer o desempenho do seu banco.

Se você tiver o phpmyadmin instalado pode usar a busca, selecionando o banco ao invés das tabelas.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'nome-do-banco';

[Retirado daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62/como-pegar-o-nome-de-todas-as-tabelas-de-uma-database-mysql)

Comment: Mas aeh ele lista apenas o nome das colunas. Preciso fazer algo assim: select * from banco_de_dados_todo WHERE * = palavra_chave

Comment: Coloque um AND table_name = "$TABLE_NAME";